# Read multi lists related data with Entity Framework 6 using ViewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want using EF 6 on my MVC 5 MarketPlace project. I have many related rows at my Database. When I using the Context Models Everything fine but I cant use ViewModels for accessing related data. I am newbie so I read about Lazy, Eager, and Explicit Loading of Related Data. When codes calling to controller with a ID then target row and relates responded as well, but I want list all of my Categories rows and they related rows at Home Index so I need a little tips please if is possible.

**Model**

```
    public partial class Category : Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Entity
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.CategoryPictures = new List<CategoryPicture>();
        this.CategoryListingTypes = new List<CategoryListingType>();
        this.CategoryStats = new List<CategoryStat>();
        this.Listings = new List<Listing>();
        this.MetaCategories = new List<MetaCategory>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public int Ordering { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryListingType> CategoryListingTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryStat> CategoryStats { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Listing> Listings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryPicture> CategoryPictures { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MetaCategory> MetaCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
    public class CategoryItemModel
{
    public List<ListingItemModel> CategoryListings { get; set; }
    public List<Category> CategoryOthers { get; set; }
    public Category CategoryCurrent { get; set; }
    public string UrlPicture { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryPictureModel> Pictures { get; set; }
}
```

**Category Details Controller**

```
 public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Category(int id)
    {
        var itemQuery = await _categoryService.Query(x => x.ID == id)
            .Include(x => x.CategoryPictures)
            .Include(x => x.CategoryListingTypes)
            .Include(x => x.Listings)
            .Include(x => x.CategoryStats)
            .SelectAsync();

        var item = itemQuery.FirstOrDefault();
        if (item == null)
            return new HttpNotFoundResult();

        var itemsList = _listingService.Queryable()
            .Where(x => x.CategoryID == id
                && (x.Enabled != false || x.Active != false)
                && (x.EndDate >= DateTime.Now || x.StartDate <= DateTime.Now))
                .ToList();

        var itemsModel = new List<ListingItemModel>();
        foreach (var list in itemsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created))
        {
            itemsModel.Add(new ListingItemModel()
            {
                ListingCurrent = list,
                UrlPicture = list.ListingPictures.Count == 0 ? ImageHelper.GetListingImagePath(0) : ImageHelper.GetListingImagePath(list.ListingPictures.OrderBy(x => x.Ordering).FirstOrDefault().PictureID)
            });
        }


        var pictures = await _categoryPictureservice.Query(x => x.CategoryID == id).SelectAsync();

        var picturesModel = pictures.Select(x =>
            new CategoryPictureModel()
            {
                ID = x.PictureID,
                Url = ImageHelper.GetCategoryImagePath(x.PictureID),
                CategoryID = x.CategoryID,
                Ordering = x.Ordering
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Ordering).ToList();

        var itemModel = new CategoryItemModel()
        {
            CategoryCurrent = item,
            CategoryListings = itemsModel,
            Pictures = picturesModel

        };

        return View("~/Views/Listing/Category.cshtml", itemModel);
    }
```

Please I want List all of my categories with they related data's (Pics, Listings, Stats).
Very Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Categories()
    {
        var items = await _categoryService.GetAll()
            .Include(x => x.CategoryPictures)
            .Include(x => x.CategoryListingTypes)
            .Include(x => x.Listings)
            .Include(x => x.CategoryStats)
            .ToListAsync();



        return View(items);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want List all of my categories with they related data's (Pics, Listings, Stats)

Then run ToList on your query:

```
    var  categories = await _categoryService.Query(x => x.ID == id)
        .Include(x => x.CategoryPictures)
        .Include(x => x.CategoryListingTypes)
        .Include(x => x.Listings)
        .Include(x => x.CategoryStats)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you but response null reference! from where you get that id?

Comment: Please post a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)